# How to remove ubuntu-desktop completely and retain gnome-shell?

Tags: gnome, 14.04

I have installed `gnome-shell` and want to remove `ubuntu-desktop`. How do I do that without destroying `gnome-shell`? Because, right now, I got many duplicates, e.g. two software updater and two system settings.

Answer (score 11):

First, install the full ubuntu-gnome-desktop metapackage to get all that comes with the full ubuntu-gnome-desktop:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Next, remove the ubuntu-desktop:

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop unity && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

or, if you would like to remove the configuration files as well

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-desktop unity unity-greeter && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

**Just BE CAREFUL to review the list of programs to uninstall before selecting "Y" to accept the changes to ensure sure you are not uninstalling something you want to keep or need!!!**

If there are any applications you want or need to keep that are to be removed, do not except the changes and instead, press CRTL + <kbd>C</kbd> to exit the command and then explicitly install these applications using `sudo apt-get install` to mark these wanted or needed applications as selected. After doing this, run `sudo apt-get autoremove` again and once more, review the list of applications to be removed to verify before accepting the changes to the system.

Comment: I also had to remove `rm /etc/init/lightdm.conf`

Comment: @Stanislav That is a result of the unity-greeter; I have included that in the uninstall command. On the newer versions, lightdm.conf is now depreciated and there should be a file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf. Alternatively, gnome doesn't use lightdm so if you run `dpkg-reconfigure gdm` and you can select gdm to be the default display manager.

Comment: don't run this command if you like your ubuntu os being able to connect to a network as it auto removes network-manager-gnome along with network-manager

Comment: @JamesKirkby I'm sorry to hear this happened to you, apt-get is certainly not perfect.  Let me just say that what you experienced is quite un-typical on Ubuntu at least (more common on Debian) and should not occur on a normally configured Ubuntu system. With that said, I cannot stress enough that whenever running *any* apt-get command,  you should *never*, *ever* type Y and press enter *without first reviewing the changes to be made to the system*. If you don't agree with the changes to be made, type `-n` or press CTRL+C to exit the command. You should also never include the `-y` flag *ever*.

Comment: @JamesKirkby All you have to do to prevent this is to run:  `sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome network-manager` before running the command and those applications will then be marked as selected packages and thus will not be removed when you run `autoremove`. In fact, you can go through the listed applications that appear in the autoremove suggestion that appears from time to time, explicitly `sudo apt-get install` any application in that list you want to keep before running autoremove and then there should be no problem.

Comment: Gnome also contains a  network manager version. I've run the very same commmands in my VM and worked fine.

Comment: Ah, i see what's missing. You want to install ubuntu-gnome-desktop package. Gnome-shell by itself just gives GUI

Comment: @Serg Thanks, I've updated the answer to include this.

Comment: To avoid intaling 500Mb of packages, only to be removed later, do `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop`. Followed by `sudo apt-get remove ...`