# after installation kubuntu some application launcher icon missing

Tags: kubuntu, launcher, icons

After installation kubuntu some application launcher icon missing.Please check screen-shot

I have already try moving .kde,cache and .local file but not got any success.
[image: Icon missing like education,games,Graphics]
Please help !

Comment: Try another icon theme.

Comment: Can you check in the System Settings which icon theme you are using? Sometimes they get corrupted and you have to reinstall them by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall INSERTICONPACKAGENAMEHERE` from a terminal.

Comment: It use default theme.I have try the given  command udo apt-get install --reinstall  breeze
but no luck..

Comment: 2018 and the problem still exists on 16.04 LTS. Rather frustrating on a multi-seat family computer or small business client installations where different users expect to use Unity or KDE depending on their preference -- I happen to personally face *both* situations. Symlinks win the day -- but its a dumb hack, and figuring out what symlinks work for what programs is an unnecessary PITA.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and it was because I installed ubuntu-desktop on my kubuntu. All icons for non "native" kubuntu applications were gone.

I fixed it by removing the ubuntu-desktop, unity and unity-greeter ([How to remove ubuntu-desktop completely and retain gnome-shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483612/how-to-remove-ubuntu-desktop-completely-and-retain-gnome-shell)).

After logging in and out the icons were appearing again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same problem. I've got at least most icons fixed via adding the package:

```
gtk2-engine-oxygen
```

and changing afterwards in *System Settings -> Application Style -> GTK* the GTK2 Theme to `oxygen-gtk` and the Fallback theme to Oxygen. After a reboot most icons are viewed correctly. The ones I'm still missing are Firefox and Thunderbird, but the rest is in place.

The page that mentioned this solution also stated, that the GTK3 Theme should also be switched to `oxygen-gtk`. That would be the package `gtk3-engine-oxygen`. I can't say much about that since I've done all this with Ubuntu Xenial and an additional installed KDE via `kubuntu-desktop` and apt-get states me that the `gtk3-package` doesn't exist.

EDIT:
The missing gtk3-package is `gtk3-engines-breeze`.

Comment: Firefox is the one I'm trying to fix :/

Comment: @JonathanNeufeld : I fixed fixed a missing firefox icon by making a symlink to it.

Comment: `ln -s /usr/share/pixmaps/firefox.png /usr/share/icons/breeze/apps/48/`. This could fail, since the firefox icon in `/pixmaps/` is only a smylink. If it fails, use the original file. Same goes for thunderbird, btw.

Comment: @MoritzDafelmair You should make this into an answer. I has been two years and the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Kubuntu 16.04.

Following the suggestion from [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kubuntu-meta/+bug/1450068), I fixed it by adding the line

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=kde
```

to ~/.profile