# After shutdown lubuntu loads up ubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu

I had latest version of lubuntu on my desktop PC, it worked fine for couple of days. Last nigh I shut down PC and when I turned it on this morning it loads Ubuntu, which is to slow on my configuration. Is there any way to revert it back?

Comment: Did you install Lubuntu on top of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove the ubuntu-desktop metapackage (and unity) - which will prevent your computer from autostarting in the Unity desktop environment.

This command should completely remove the Ubuntu desktop, Unity, the Unity greeter, and relevant configuration files.

`sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-desktop unity unity-greeter && sudo apt-get autoremove`

You will want to make sure to read the list of packages that will be removed, to make sure it doesn't remove a package you want to use.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/483627/103537